# linux mint immediately wakes up after going into standby mode

Tags: linux

Windows sleep mode work fine. linux mint not work. wakes up after going into standby mode immediately. 1 sec max

```
[ 4152.930790] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 4153.271045] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 4153.271097] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 4153.272696] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline

[ 4153.289514] smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
[ 4153.290053] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
[ 4153.290074] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[ 4153.290274] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
[ 4153.290666] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 4153.290698] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[ 4153.290698] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 4153.290807] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x0a201016
[ 4153.293344] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 2 idle states
[ 4153.293514] CPU1 is up

[ 4153.318886] CPU11 is up
[ 4153.319861] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[ 4153.407888] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[ 4153.407889] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[ 4153.407890] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Starting disk
[ 4153.408537] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
[ 4153.408539] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 4153.408540] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 4153.409056] serial 00:04: activated
[ 4153.418775] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.2: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
[ 4153.418777] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 4153.418777] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[ 4153.500458] nvme nvme0: 15/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[ 4153.719380] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)

[ 4153.839433] usb 1-10: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 4153.939274] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4153.941142] ata4.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[ 4153.941498] ata4.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[ 4153.942044] ata4.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[ 4153.942383] ata4.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[ 4153.942759] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4154.335399] usb 1-2: reset low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4154.719275] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4154.761935] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4154.907399] usb 1-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 4155.205053] OOM killer enabled.
[ 4155.205054] Restarting tasks ... done.
[ 4155.207469] PM: suspend exit
[ 4157.011258] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 4157.030624] ata1.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
[ 4157.031919] ata1.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
[ 4157.031924] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 4157.099259] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-400:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-400:00, irq=MAC)
[ 4157.303498] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Down
[ 4162.714007] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 4162.714021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready



Current Boot Loader:
      Product: n/a
     Features: ✗ Boot counting
               ✗ Menu timeout control
               ✗ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✗ Default entry control
               ✗ One-shot entry control
               ✗ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✗ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✗ Boot loader sets ESP information
          ESP: n/a
         File: └─n/a
```